# \link[grDevices]{win.metafile} in Rd: how to pass R CMD check warning from a UNIX environment?

Tags: windows, r, unix, roxygen2, rd

I'm working in a UNIX environment and making a package where an utility function's `Rd` needs to link to `grDevices::win.metafile` help page (that is Windows-specific). My `.R` file (using `roxygen2`) is

```
#' Open a vectorial device file in a portable way.                              
#'                                                                              
#'                                                                              
#' Portable function which choose what (vectorial) device to open looking at    
#' the system.                                                                  
#'                                                                              
#'                                                                              
#' @usage graph(file, width, height, ...)                                       
#' @param file path without extension                                           
#' @param width width in inches                                                 
#' @param height height in inches                                               
#' @param ... other arguments passed to \code{\link{pdf}} or                    
#' \code{\link[grDevices]{win.metafile}}                                        
#' @return Values returned by pdf or win.metafile?                              
#' @keywords pdf win.metafile vectorial graph                                   
#' @export graph                                                                
graph <- function(file="", width = 7,
                  height = 7,  ...) {

    if (Sys.info()["sysname"]=="Linux") {
        path <- paste(file, "pdf" ,sep=".")
        pdf(file=path, width = width, height = height, ...)
    } else if (Sys.info()["sysname"]=="Windows") {
        path <- paste(file, "emf" ,sep=".")
        win.metafile(filename=path, width = width, height = height, ...)
    }
}
```

However, when going to `R CMD check`, a WARNING is issued:

```
Missing link or links in documentation object 'graph.Rd':
  ‘[grDevices]{win.metafile}’
See the information in section 'Cross-references' of the 'Writing R
Extensions' manual.
```

I've looked at *Cross-references* of *Writing R Extensions* but the only alternative method seems to be `[grDevices:win.metafile]{win.metafile}`, that gives the same results (and honestly speaking i didn't understand fully its meaning).

Any hint to "shut up" the checks? Thanks, Luca

Comment: isnt that just a note? if you're on a unix, you wouldnt have that function or device. I don't think you can shut them up, though. I get the same things for referencing in-house packages

Comment: @rawr, no it's a warning. Thanks

Comment: … and it should be a warning. Unfortunately, as long as you miss the Rd file that you are referencing, you will get a warning. You might be able to spoof the checker by copying the file manually.